# Best setup to develop cross-platform GUI-based apps using Python

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I have been using `REALbasic` for a number of years to develop cross-platform apps.  I have become frustrated developing with a proprietary language and so have decided to change languages and have settled on `Python` and `QT`.

Since I know no Python, would people recommend Python 2 or 3?

I think I will be using `PyQt` or `PySide`. I know that of these two, only PyQt (currently) supports Python 3.  Does this give enough of an advantage over PySide? It's just that PySide seems to have a 'cleaner' syntax.

Answer (score 1):

PySide and PyQt4 are almost identical. In fact, you can often replace `PyQt4` with `PySide` (and vice versa) in your code's import declarations.

Python2 and Python3 are almost identical as well, with a few minor changes that a beginner won't notice for a while (aside from `print` being made a function).

Python2 has more support in terms of modules (Python3 broke backwards-compatibility with Python2), so I'd suggest you use Python2 until you figure out a reason to switch to Python3. There really is no benefit, as both releases are maintained separately.

---

In short, stick with the stuff that's known to work.

Comment: Currently, most major packages support py3k (matplotlib, numpy, scipy, pyQt to name a few). Even Django has already passed all the test. From now on, development is going to be made only on py3k. py3k is not the future, it is already here. And I already switched. The OP is a newcomer to python. He probably should better start with the code that is here to prevail in the next years.

Comment: I doubt Python2 will be dropped any time soon, but yes, most *major* packages support Python3. I was referring more to less-developed modules, code you find on the internet (like SO), etc.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt and PySide are mostly identical. The major difference is the licensing. PyQt is GPL, and when selling an app, it requires a commercial license, where PySide has a LGPL license allowing you to sell your code without buying a license. Nice thing is, you can just switch the imports and sell it. :) PySide is also 2.x only, where PyQt is both.

[PySide funding is ending as well](http://lists.pyside.org/pipermail/pyside/2011-August/002816.html).

**"It's just that PySide seems to have a 'cleaner' syntax."**

PyQt uses api 1 in 2.x (switchable to api 2 using `sip.setapi(2, 'item')`), and api 2 in 3.x. Switching to api 2 will have the same syntax as in PySide and PyQt in 3.x.

A nice article explaining differences between api 1 and api 2 can be found in [PSEP 101](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pseps/psep-0101.html).

**"Since I know no Python, would people recommend Python 2 or 3?"**

You're more likely to use Python 2 as very many modules and libraries haven't yet made the switch to Python 3, as it was an incompatible release against Python 2 (it's been 3 years since 2008 when Py3k came out!).

Just go with which one fits your best needs considering the circumstances. Some people like PyQt more because it's been around longer, is a more mature project, and is likely to be more stable because of that. Although, I've never really had any problems with PySide either, so it should be fine.

Comment: Update about pyside funding - the Qt company seems to be funding it - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyside-dev/pqwzngAGLWE

Answer (score 0):

On the question of "Python2 or Python3?", I would suggest you read [this article](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) on the Python Wiki. As well as giving detailed answers to most of the main questions you might have on this topic, it also has a lot of links that you will probably find useful.

As for "PyQt or PySide?": from a pure coding point of view, the differences are minimal, especially to a beginner (for details, see [this artical](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt) on the Qt Wiki). The only significant difference between PyQt and PySide is licensing (GPL vs LGPL).

PyQt is a much more mature project than PySide, and is more flexible when it comes to compatibility with Qt and Python versions. The Sip package (which PyQt depends on), also allows you to fine-tune the use of different API versions at run-time (see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/incompatible_apis.html?highlight=setapi) for details).

Overall, the "safest" short-term choice would probably be PyQt+Python2. There is a *lot* more code out there for PyQt than there is for PySide, and for Python2 than there is for Python3, and it is likely to stay that way for quite some time. So, as a beginner, it will do you no harm to start with that combination, as (leaving licensing issues aside) it will be relatively painless to make the switch later on if necessary.

Comment: "PySide and Python3" - PySide doesn't support Python 3.

Comment: @JohnDoe. I know. The sentence is meant to refer to "the amount of code out there" for each individually, not in combination.

Comment: It's sort of misleading, since there's 0 code out there with PySide and Python 3. Saying there's more PyQt and Python 2 than PySide and Python 2 is valid though, or even more PyQt apps than PySide apps (put more simply).

Comment: @JohnDoe. I think it's more a case of misreading than misleading - but I've reformulated the sentence now, so hopefully my meaning is clear.